# Set environment variables from command line - and make them stick globally

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them)

In Windows 2008 Server R2, once I set an environment variable in the command line, how can I make it stick?
For example, it's easy to write:

> set path=%path%;

much easier than the crummy right-click My Computer method.  But once I set this, the changes disappear with my command window.  How to make them stick?  I want to do the same with JAVA_HOME and some others as well.

Comment: setx may be best.. But cmd /? also mentions HKLM or HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun  a bat file there could have the set PATH=.... line.

Comment: @barlop: Setting "permanent" envvars through cmd's AutoRun is a hack. The page @slhck linked to has a better location - `HKCU\Environment`, which is loaded by Winlogon itself. (It's what setx uses, too.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in more detail in [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables), you can use `setx` to set a variable permanently:

```
setx MyVariable "C:\Path\to\Folder"
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Path\to\Java"
```

et cetera.